# Saving flash runtime data on the fly

Tags: flash, save, audio-recording

I'm working on an application for users to record audio using a microphone and save it on our servers. I'm using Flash. As far as I can tell, there is no way for me to autosave for my users.

How can I 'autosave' the recording without having my users click "Save"? Otherwise their recording could be lost if, for example, their browser crashes in the middle of a recording.

Comment: If you are saving it on your servers, what is stopping you from sending the data to a server side script and saving it at any point in time during the recording?

Comment: I'm a musician primarily, not a hacker, but my understanding of the application my friend and I are making is that it only allows for saving to our server via a click on the client side.  My concern is that SOME clients may lose data (because of a loss of connection for instance).  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer to send that data systematically to your server and keep the last saved block (of recording) as a temp file just in case user encounters such an issue. Once the user hits the stop button, you can send **the whole** recording to your server, which will save it as a sound file (wav or mp3 I guess) and delete the older temp file.

Comment: OK.  Thanks, we'll probably use this method :)